# Why doesn't my OpenGL Radar implementation render on screen?

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to implement radar for my 3D game using openGL.  I have been trying to accomplish it in many ways, but none of them approved to be correct. Here is the snippet of my code below:

```
int xi, yi;
GLfloat x,z;
glPushMatrix();
{
    glTranslatef(-0.8f, 0.2f, -3.0f);

    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    x = playerTank->givePosX();
    z = playerTank->givePosZ();
    xi = (int)((x + 1000) / 20) + 5;
    yi = (int)(((z + 1000) / 20) + screenHeight - 105);
    glPushMatrix();
    {
        glScalef(xi,yi,1.0f);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex2i(xi-5, yi-5);
        glVertex2i(xi+5, yi-5);
        glVertex2i(xi+5, yi+5);
        glVertex2i(xi-5, yi+5);
        glEnd();
    }
    glPopMatrix();

    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glPushMatrix();
    {
        glScalef(xi,yi,1.0f);
        for (int i = 0; i < tanks.size(); i++)
        {
            x = tanks[i]->givePosX();
            z = tanks[i]->givePosZ();
            xi = (int)((x + 1000) / 20) + 5;
            yi = (int)(((z + 1000) / 20) + screenHeight - 105);
            if (xi > 0 && xi < 110 && yi > (screenHeight - 110) && yi < screenHeight)
            {
                if (tanks[i] != playerTank)
                {
                    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
                    glVertex2i(xi, yi-5);
                    glVertex2i(xi+5, yi+5);
                    glVertex2i(xi-5, yi+5);
                    glEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    glPopMatrix();

    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glPushMatrix();
    {
        glScalef(xi,yi,1.0f);
        for (int i = 0; i < obstacles.size(); i++)
        {
            x = obstacles[i]->givePosX();
            z = obstacles[i]->givePosZ();
            xi = (int)((x + 1000) / 20) + 5;
            yi = (int)(((z + 1000) / 20) + screenHeight - 105);

            glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
            glVertex2i(xi-3, yi-3);
            glVertex2i(xi+3, yi-3);
            glVertex2i(xi+3, yi+3);
            glVertex2i(xi-3, yi+3);
            glEnd();
        }
    }
    glPopMatrix();
}
glPopMatrix();
```

Why doesn't anything appear on the screen?

Comment: Specifically what is the problem? What's incorrect with your current implementation?

Comment: You're overwriting the values of `xi` and `yi` in the tank loop, and then using them in a `glScalef()` before the obstacle loop.  Is this intended?

Comment: @JonCage , I don't know it either, I was hoping someone will tell me. :( It gives me nothing on my screen, so it's a bit confusing to me why won't this work. !genpflaut Good observation, will fix it now and see what happens then.

Comment: @Takarakaka: Nothing at all?  Not even the blue player tank square?  How are your `GL_PROJECTION` and `GL_MODELVIEW` matrices set up before you try to draw the minimap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to try:

1. Make sure you've set up the renderer correctly - what calls are you making to set up the scene? Take a look at [some of the lessons on nehe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) for some hints.
2. Make a simple square the size of the screen. You're doing something along those lines in the top section (blue quad right?) but make sure it's centred - looks like you might be pushing it up and right by 1000 units.
3. Check you're winding the correct way. Looks like you are from my somewhat rusty OGL memories.
4. Try translating in different directions. Looks to me like you might be translating the wrong way with your first `translatef`.

Comment: great! will try them all and see what happens.

Comment: I have set up the object on the scene, however it is too large, so I am now in dilemma whether to use glOrtho or to change glTranslate parameters? Btw. Thanks on the help! :)

Comment: No problem - I remember running into the exact same sort of issues when I was starting out with OpenGL. I just wish I'd had stackoverflow in those days! You could always scale the numbers you're using down a bit if they're too big for the screen...

Comment: Well you know what stage I am going through right now then. :) I have finally made it working now! Many thanks for the help, @Jon Cage! ;)